# Make a link be the same height even if the text wraps

Tags: html, css

I have several image + text combos that I'd like to make links. However some of the text portions are long enough that the text has to wrap. I'd like to keep the overall divs the same height, with just whitespace below, and I've mostly achieved this, however the single line links justify the whole div down a line.

```
<h1>KIDS CATALOG</h1>
<div class='ecat'>
<a href="">
<img  src="/images/elabels/ABC123.png" class="elabel"><br>
<span class="linklabel">ABC's &amp; 123's</span></a></div>
<div class='ecat'>
<a href="">
<img  src="/images/elabels/ANIMALS.png" class="elabel"><br>
<span class="linklabel">Animals</span></a></div>
<div class='ecat'>
<a href="">
<img  src="/images/elabels/BEACHANDOCEAN.png" class="elabel"><br>
<span class="linklabel">Beach &amp; Oceans</span></a></div>
```

and the style:

```
.elabel {width:100px;}
.ecat a{font-weight:bold;}
.ecat:hover {background:yellow;}
.ecat {display:inline-block; 
  background:white; 
  margin:5px; 
  padding:5px; 
  min-width:100px; 
  max-width:120px; 
  height:160px; 
  border: 2px solid #09c; }
```

[image: Animals is misalinged]

Comment: Could you provide a executable code snippet? Due to inefficient code provided, I can't get the same results in the image you have shown.

Comment: https://www.quackit.com/css/flexbox/examples/flexbox_cards.cfm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083516/alignment-issue-with-inline-blocks-of-different-heights

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, using flexbox I was able to achieve what I set out to do. Please feel free to expand your first comment into a full answer.

Answer (score -2):

add align-down to 2nd div's class and put this in CSS:

```
  .align-down{
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
  }
```

You can change the class name and the alignment too.